# Azure PCA-Based Anomaly Detection

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-ml-component

I'm trying to create an anomaly detection model to be able to detect odd new entries in my dataset.

I'm using Azure ML Studio and using the PCA-Based Anomaly Detection component. One of the options of this component is called "Training mode" and reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/component-reference/pca-based-anomaly-detection?view=azureml-api-2#how-to-configure-pca-based-anomaly-detection) I should be able to set it to either "SingleParameter" or "ParameterRange". But when I add the component and try to set it up I only see the option "SingleParameter" available.

[image: Info about available options]
[image: Dropdown open with SingleParameter only]

Did someone know why and if I can unlock it ? I would like to plug the PCA-Based Anomaly Detection component to a sweep parameters component but I think I can't do that is the Training mode is not set up to "ParameterRange".

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/machine-learning/component-reference/train-anomaly-detection-model.md) it seems like the Azure ML Studio only support the `SingleParameter` training mode. So, you can't use the PCA-Based Anomaly Detection component with the sweep parameters.

However, one possible workaround to this can be with [Tune Model Hyperparameters component.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/machine-learning/component-reference/tune-model-hyperparameters.md)
With this component you perform a parameter sweep to tune hyper-parameters as this component supports a parameter range and can be used with the PCA-Based Anomaly Detection component.
[image]